# How can I apply an asynchronism to a firebase function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that sends data to the firebase realtime database. Now I'm creating a dashboard to manage this data. At the moment I need to receive a notification on the dashboard when the user sends some new data to the firebase. I need to receive a message with the data id he sent and submit a notification similar to a social network.

I'm using FCM, I've already configured and tried to implement the onCreate () function. But when the bank is upgrading, this function is not being performed.

I'm implementing the code in the dashboard 
I believe it is a lack of asynchronism. is there any way to apply it to the function call?

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");

  const admin = require("firebase-admin");
  admin.initializeApp();

  exports.makeUppercase = functions.database
    .ref("/users/{userID}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();

      console.log("new User " + original);
    });
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "a lack of asynchronism".

Comment: As I understand the issue is that the function is not triggered at all. Could it be that you are updating some existing data and not uploading new one to the database. In that case maybe you should use the `onWrite()` event handler to trigger your function. In any case could you elaborate more on your use case and let us know more details and any documentation that you have followed?

Comment: So, I just want to make my console print the new firebase user. But the function is not firing when receiving the new user. Maybe it's some asymmetrical problem, that's what I thought.

Comment: What do you mean by asymmetrical problem? Could you explain this a bit? Did you follow my suggestion to trigger your function with a different [handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)?